# ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional (NeuralNetwork)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I am making a prediction and implementing a neural network, is currently working with the numpy library and I am adapting the code to the data that I have.

I leave the current progress of the neural network, I have an error at the end of the code and I do not understand it well.
Anyone who can help me please?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

class LinearLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_input, n_output):
        self.n = n_input
        self.m = n_output
        self.W = (1/np.sqrt(n_input))*np.random.rand(n_input+1, n_output)

    def forward(self, X):
        self.input = np.zeros((X.shape[0],self.n+1))
        # if only one feature, the input should always be a batch, at least
        if len(X.shape) == 1:  # of one element
            self.input[:-1,:] = X.reshape(-1,self.n)
        else:
            self.input[:,:-1] = X

        self.input[:,-1] = 1
        self.output = self.input.dot(self.W) # xW + b
        return self.output


    def backward(self, d_out):
        self.gradients = self.W.dot(d_out)[:-1]
        self.dW = np.einsum("ij,ki", self.input, d_out)
        return self.gradients


    def updateWeights(self, lr=0.1):
        self.W = self.W - lr*self.dW


class Sigmoid:
    def __init__(self, n_input):
        self.output = np.zeros(n_input)
        self.gradients = np.zeros(n_input)        


    def forward(self, X):
        self.output = 1/(np.exp(-X)+1)
        return self.output


    def backward(self, d_out):
        ds = self.output.T*(1 - self.output).T
        self.gradients = ds*d_out
        return self.gradients



print("Training a multilayer perceptron\n")
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Data_Balanceada.csv') #Data (74,11)
X = data.iloc[:,0:11]
y = data.iloc[:,-1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)

h1 = LinearLayer(11,1)  #stack some layers
s1 = Sigmoid(7) 
h2 = LinearLayer(7,1)
s2 = Sigmoid(1)

def loss(pred, target):
    return np.mean(np.power(pred-target,2))

predict = lambda x: s2.forward(h2.forward(s1.forward(h1.forward(x))))
backpropagate = lambda d: h1.backward(s1.backward(h2.backward(s2.backward(d))))

lr = 0.005
n = 0 # patience
max_epochs = 1500
valid = loss(predict(X_test), y_test) 
for i in range(max_epochs):
    l = 0
    p = predict(X_train)  
    backpropagate(p.T-y_train.T)
    h1.updateWeights(lr)
    h2.updateWeights(lr)
    l = loss(p,y_train)
    new_valid = loss(predict(X_test), y_test)
    if new_valid < valid:
        valid = new_valid
        n = 0
    else:
        n += 1
    if n > 50:  break
    if i%50 == 0:   
        print("Loss: {0}\t\tValidation: {1}".format(l/100, valid))
        lr = lr*0.97


# Validation
print("\nFinal validation loss: {0}. {1} epochs\n".format(loss(predict(X_test), y_test),i+1))
#print(np.argmax(predict(X_test), axis=1))
#print(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1))
```

link Dataset:

https://mega.nz/#!jM8AQAbB!61NOeJadGXtiKJQsn_tdJ955p5lRD6kQjBlCQTHtt6I

I have this error:

```
Data must be 1-dimensional
```

IMG - ERROR

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us the full traceback, and not just the error message?  Be sure to edit it into the question instead of replying in the comments (comments are not very good for showing big complicated code blocks, and we prefer to have all the information in one place).

Comment: @Kevin I uploaded the error image